# Why am I getting an error trying to upload a large file?

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I am using Laravel and want to upload a 3GB video but get this error:

```
Request Entity Too Large
The requested resource does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.1.12 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
419
Page Expired
```

My code:

```php
if($request->has('videos_path')){
  $request->validate([
      'videos_path'=>'required|file|max:380928|mimetypes:video/mp4',
  ]);
  $extension = strtolower($request->videos_path->extension());
  $filename = time() . rand(100, 999) . '.' . $extension;
  $request->videos_path->getClientOriginalName = $filename;

  $request->videos_path->move('assets/admin/uploads/movies/videos', $filename);
  $data['videos_path']= 'assets/admin/uploads/movies/videos/'. $filename;
}
```

And in php.ini:

```
max_input_time=1080
post_max_size=4096M
upload_max_filesize= 4096M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice no to upload large files as normal form field. Upload them as subsequent chunks.

`Chunked upload is the process of breaking a file into smaller pieces, upload 'as is' and glue pieces into original file on the server side.`

You can check [this link](https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/laravel-guides/laravel-chunked-upload-uploading-huge-files) for more detail.

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the actual question, this is a working workaround. Upvoted.

Comment: thx man -- not like i want but will do the job

Answer (score 0):

When you want to upload a large file, you need to adjust both your Apache server settings and your PHP configuration. So you need to add `LimitRequestBody 0` to your `.htaccess` file.

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-limiting-upload-size/